# RadioButton Error in html Page

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

in my project I have two checkboxes and which has background image. when I remove those buckground image proprty, the checkbox not shows. can any one solve the issue ?

please find my code in js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/p9oL589k)

HTML:

```
<table id="rbtnsslEnabled" class="chkMargin">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="rbtnsslEnabled_0" type="radio" name="rbtnsslEnabled" value="SSL" />
                <label for="rbtnsslEnabled_0">SSL</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="rbtnsslEnabled_1" type="radio" name="rbtnsslEnabled" value="TLS" />
                <label for="rbtnsslEnabled_1">TLS</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100% !important;
    border: none;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
input[type=checkbox]:not(old), input[type=radio]:not(old) {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label, input[type=radio]:not(old) + label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -28px;
    padding-left: 28px;
    background: url('http://s6.postimg.org/4e4im9vkt/checks.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px \9;
    line-height: normal;
}
input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label {
    background-position: 0 -24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below css is intentionally hiding the (default) radio button:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old), input[type=radio]:not(old) {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

specifically

```
opacity: 0;
```

The purpose of which is to give you the fancy "green check box" style radio buttons. Since the default button is hidden, the background is taking the place of the button, so hiding the background, now also hides the button. If you want to just use normal radio buttons, remove the `opacity: 0;` style [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9oL589k/2/), or even that entire block ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9oL589k/3/))